# How can a string be a Referential Data Type in JAVA?

Tags: java

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String se = new String("Hello world");
        String sx = se;
        sx = "Hello aliens";
        System.out.println(se);
        System.out.println(sx);
    }
}
```

Here, `se` stores "Hello world" and `sx=se` which means `sx` and `se` must point to same memory location. If `sx` is changed to "Hello aliens" then `se` must also be changed. But the above code prints the following:

`Hello world`
`Hello aliens`

Then how are Strings called Referential Data Types?

Comment: *"`sx=se` means `sx` and `se` must point to same memory"*! so, same logic, `sx="Hello aliens"` means that now `sx` points to same memory as `"Hello aliens"` (not `se` anymore) (( no need for `new String("Hello World")`; `"Hello World"` is already a `String` object {despite a different one} ))

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Java are immutable, which means you can't change them once they are created.  You're not changing the originally referenced string; you are **creating a new string.**

This is how strings work throughout Java.  If you look at the string manipulation methods for the String class in the Java documentation, you'll see that *they all return a new string,* rather than modifying the original one in-place.

Answer (score 1):

You created two completely separate pointers, that happen to be pointing to the same memory location:

```
String se = new String("Hello world");
String sx = se;
```

Those pointers are not linked together in any way. When you change one it doesn't change the other.

Here you are changing one of those pointers to point to a different memory location:

```
sx = "Hello aliens";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String se = new String("Hello world");
```

Now we have a variable `se`, which points to a string `"Hello world"`. Simple enough.

```
    String sx = se;
```

Now we have a variable `sx` and a variable `se`, which both point to `"Hello world"`. In this case, they point to the exact same string object, but generally speaking in Java we don't like to care about that; the JVM does just fine managing string objects without us having to think about it.

```
    sx = "Hello aliens";
```

Now we've changed what the *variable* `sx` points to. We haven't said anything at all about `se`. So `sx` points to `"Hello aliens"` and `se` to `"Hello world"`, since we haven't changed anything on the `se` side.

If you're trying to understand reference semantics, strings are a bad example, since they're immutable in Java. Consider making a simple class like the following.

```
public class MyContainer {
  public int value;
  public MyContainer(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Then make a few instances of `MyContainer` and do basically what you did with the strings with it. If two variables point to the same `MyContainer` and you change `value` on one, it'll be reflected in the other, but not if you change where the variable points.

```
MyContainer a = new MyContainer(0);
MyContainer b = a;
// a.value and b.value are both 0 here.
a.value = 99;
// a.value and b.value are both 99 here.
b = new MyContainer(100);
// a.value is still 99; we only changed b here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
// "Hello world" literal is stored in StringPool
// se is a reference to the object String in heap that holds "Hello world"
String se = new String("Hello world");

// sx is the another reference to the same String object that se referes
String sx = se;

// "Hello aliens" literal is stored in StringPool
// sx is the same reference but now it refers to the "Hello aliens" literal in the StringPool
sx = "Hello aliens";

// print string by se reference, wich is "Hello World"
System.out.println(se);

// print string by sx reference, which is "Hello aliens"
System.out.println(sx)
```

I hope it helps you to understand of references.